# 2 different Django modules on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I came across 2 different modules for porting Django to App Engine:

http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/

http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/

Both seem to be compatible with Django 1.0,

The featured download of the latter is in Aug 08, whereas the former is Feb 09.

What are the relative merits?

What if I don't use the database at all, would it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit late to answer, but the problem I've had so far with app-engine-patch is that, while it's a generally feature-complete port of Django 1.0, it discards Django models in favor of AppEngine's db.Model.

It's understandable, given the differences between the two, but it can require quite a bit of effort to port, depending on how involved your models (and usage of those models; this means you lose the Django query syntax as well).

Answer (score 6):

At the moment, the App Engine Patch is outdated.

Djangoappengine and Django-Nonrel provide "Native Django on App Engine": 
http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/01/Native-Django-on-App-Engine

Comment: There is an updated post here: http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it myself. I used python 2.6, and it seem problmatic for app-engine. Starting with python2.5 solved it. 
See [here:](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=3&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fgoogleappengine%2Fissues%2Fdetail%3Fid%3D1159&ei=dNDzSez9OcaC_Qb71NFW&usg=AFQjCNG5MMVCwbP-g1AQPxOAtxQGH1U44w&sig2=Jr29ZtKFQNpZTQULI_ieWg)

Answer (score 0):

[App Engine Patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/) is the right way to go.